# MS SQL inserts question marks instead of non-latyn symbols

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, non-ascii-characters, sql-server-2017

I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
    Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Evaluation 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

When i do: `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(COLNAME) VALUES ('Қазақстан')` it inserts question marks `?????????` instead of actual string. My column type is `NVARCHAR(255)`. If i insert `N` character before my value like this: `...(N'Қазақстан')` it will be persisted properly. Is it the only way to insert non-ASCII characters or should i change something else?

Thanks!

Comment: _Is it the only way to insert non-ASCII characters_ Yes

Comment: In Sql Server, Unicode string literals must have the `N` prefix.

Comment: How are you executing the query? In a script, a stored procedure, client code? In general you should use parameterized queries instead of hard-coded strings. If you can't, Unicode string literals must have the `N` prefix

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I just do insert and select in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes, you should use `N`

From **[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> When prefixing a string constant with the letter N, the implicit conversion will result in a UCS-2 or UTF-16 string if the constant to convert does not exceed the max length for the nvarchar string data type (4,000). Otherwise, the implicit conversion will result in a large-value nvarchar(max).

So if you don't use `N` then SQL Server will treate it as `VARCHAR` (non unicode).
Using the `N` will convert the string to unicode string.